# OpenGL ES single pixel drawing android

Tags: android, opengl-es, lwjgl, pixel

So I made an app using lwjgl for the computer and was trying to make it for android however I can't find replacement for the command glVertex3f() which I use for drawing a single pixel which my app needs to do to set the color per pixel. Is there a way to do per pixel coloring in openGL ES for android, or an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GL_POINTS` for the `mode` parameter of the `glDraw*` function. This way you could render one pixel at a time.

Comment: How do you mean? How would I do color for that?

Comment: Look at the [Khronos registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/). That is the function used for drawing in OpenGL ES. The first parameter is `mode`.

Comment: I more mean the coloring. The project requires a slightly different color on a pixel basis. I need to go afk but I'll be back later.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? Do you want to have each pixel colored differently? Should it be based on the position of the pixel on the screen or on the mesh/model?

Comment: yes. It is necessary for the correct display. A formula calculates the pixels color based on a number of things.

Comment: If you're using ES 2.x or higher than you would need to pass all the necessary data to shaders and any calculations in them.

Comment: The calculations are changed based on a variety of things... the shaders won't be able to access them. what about OpenGL 1.0?

Comment: OpenGL ES 1 has a fixed function pipeline, not sure if you could do the per-pixel calculations there using GLES. So either pass the data to the shaders somehow or calculate the values on CPU.

Comment: Yes the calculations are on the CPU for my other app as well. GPU processing is a future improvement if possible. So for OpenGL ES 1 what would the replacement command be?

Comment: Drawing every pixel with its own color

Comment: I think you would need to do the calculations on CPU and put them in a bitmap, then upload it as a texture and draw.